# forward definition of c++ class member functions

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

I'm writing a small generator which outputs c++ classes in a single cpp file from a tree object structure ( order of output of classes is given by this tree, so its fixed).

To keep it simple I would prefer if there is a way to keep it all in one file.

The problem is that these classes sometimes interact with each other using the member functions and there is the case that forward declarations arent working.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class B;
B* global_b=NULL;

class A;
A* global_a=NULL;

class A {

    public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}

    void accessB()
    {
        global_b->setValue(1);
    }

    int getValue()
    {
        return 2;
    }

};

class B {
    public:
    B() : j(0) {}
    ~B(){}

    void setValue(int i)
    {
        j = i + global_a->getValue();
    }
    int j;
};


int main()
{
    global_b = new B();
    global_a = new A();

    global_a->accessB();
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions/ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you'd do this:

```
class A {

    public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}

    void accessB();
  ...
};
```

Then somewhere after both A and B are declared:

```
void A::accessB()
{
    global_b->setValue(1);
}
```

Comment: +1. Disagree that leaving it all in one file is "keeping it simple", splitting them up like this both solves the problem, and lets you look at the interface when you want to look at the interface, and at the implementation when you want to look at that.

Comment: @Paul: The classes arent supposed to be edited manually. They are generated and the only time you need to look at it, is if there is some error. Not if you need more features or knowledge about it. So keeping it simple means, keeping the processing afford low.

Comment: @user1159208: " the only time you need to look at it, is if there is some error" - all the more reason for keeping it out of sight in separate files, then.

Comment: It is fairly common for code generators to generate huge source files. A colleague of mine worked on a project where they hit a compiler bug in 275000 lines of C (not C++). The bug was there after they chopped it down to a few hundred lines too. Most of that was one function too! ;)

Comment: I think we should start calling them dysfunctions when they start getting that large!

Comment: You could do that. But it was what this code generator did, and the company I worked for at the time used it - I didn't, I was using C and writing small functions that fit on the page, like any sane human being. Code-generators are not human tho' (and probably not sane either). By the way, most of that 200+ K lines was one big switch-statement as well... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your global values should probably be class statics.

To get forward declaration working you should specify the classes without any inline functions. Then later in the file you can write:

```
inline void B::setValue(int i)
{
  j = i + A::global.getValue();
}
```